# How to access data from Excel cells in PowerPoint (using VB 6.3)

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I would like to access data from Excel to be used in powerpoint. I have found this tutorial https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-effective-methods-to-extract-numbers-from-your-excel-cells/, but it describes how to use it in the Excel alone:

```vb
Sub ExtractNumbersFromCells()
  Dim objRange As Range, nCellLength As Integer, nNumberPosition As Integer, strTargetNumber As String

  '  Initialization
  strTargetNumber = ""

  '  Go through all the cells in the target range
  For Each objRange In Range("B4:B14")
    nCellLength = Len(objRange)

    '  Extract numbers from cells
    For nNumberPosition = 1 To nCellLength
      If IsNumeric(Mid(objRange, nNumberPosition, 1)) Then
        strTargetNumber = strTargetNumber & Mid(objRange, nNumberPosition, 1)
      End If
    Next nNumberPosition

    objRange.Offset(0, 1) = strTargetNumber
    strTargetNumber = ""
  Next objRange
End Sub
```

So for example I have my values on rows: B4:B14 ...
and I want to process them in PowerPoint. How to do that?

Comment: Is the copy/paste the only solution? Is it not possible to simply refer object in running application, eg. from PowerPoint to point to Excel object? The PowerPoint does not the excess to Excell at all? Thank you.

Comment: No you don't need to use copy/paste - you can read the cell values directly once you have a reference to the worksheet.  On review that link I posted is not a good example - let me find something more useful...

Comment: Thank you I will read the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic example of automating Excel from PPT:

```vb
'Requires VBA Project reference to "Microsoft Excel xx.0 Object Library"
Sub Tester()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application    'open Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True                 'make visible
    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Test.xlsx") 'open a workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")                   'get a worksheet reference
    
    For x = 1 To 5                       'loop over a range
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(x, 1).Value 'read cell value
    Next x
    
    wb.Close False                       'don't save changes
    xlApp.Quit                           'close excel
    
End Sub
```

Most of the VBA examples you'll find online cover automating PPT from Excel (since automating the creation of presentations using Excel data is a common use case).

Comment: Tested and works. I have just modified it to work with active document already opened according Q/A here: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/208864-referencing-opened-excel-workbook